# When and where to use FindElement method of By class

Tags: c#, selenium, webdriver

I have basic understanding of Selenium architecture, where Search Context is main interface implemented by Web Driver interface which is extended by various browser driver class. Normally, we follow POM for our selenium projects and define each object by their By class -

```
By addButton=By.Id("asdf");
```

But just realized that we can even do-

```
addButton.FindElement(By.XPath("ABC").
```

But this does not return element like `driver.FindElement(addButton)`

When to use above statement?

Comment: Are you sure that `addButton.FindElement(By.XPath("ABC"))` is a valid expression? I'm using Java, not C#, and Java doesn't accept this expression because `By.xpath("...")` is a By.class but this statements requires a `SearchContext` (e.g. chromedriver) in this combination

Comment: As far as i know, this is how we use it in Java - `driver.findElement(addButton)` . It is normally used when we try to write generic functions in Keyword Driven Framework.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

*The following is using terms from the Java-binding, but it holds true for the C#-Binding as well:*

## First

@spcial is right there is no "By.findElement(By)" defined in Selenium. Nevertheless there is a "By.findElement(SearchContext)" defined which I will explain below:

## SearchContext vs. By

In Selenium you have an interface called a [`SearchContext`](http://selenium.googlecode.com/git/docs/api/java/org/openqa/selenium/SearchContext.html) and then you have the [`By`](http://selenium.googlecode.com/git/docs/api/java/org/openqa/selenium/By.html) class.

A `SearchContext` can be a `WebElement` or a `WebDriver`

Now you have two options to find an element (using pseudo-code):

1) `SearchContext.findElement(By...)`

or

2) `By.findElement(SearchContext...)`

Both do the same thing!

Say in your case you have a driver and the By variable like this:

```
WebDriver driver = new FirefoxDriver();
By addButtonLocator = By.id("asdf");
```

now you can find your element in two ways:

1) `driver.findElement(addButtonLocator);`

or

2) `addButtonLocator.findElement(driver);`

Again! Both do the same thing, it's just another way to "read" these expressions like this:

```
1) "take the driver and search for an element using this By-statement"
```

or

```
2) "take the By-statement and search for an element that fits this statement within driver"
```

As said before, instead of a driver you can have a smaller scope if you use an already identified element.